# How install Homebrew on Mac ? dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

Tags: macos, homebrew, libssl

I already read all question on this subject but none are solving the problem, how can I install `Homebrew` on my Mac with the following error :

`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did you go to the [Homebrew home page](https://brew.sh) and follow the directions there? You should be able to search the home page for the error you get. Homebrew installed fine on my 2010 iMac.

Comment: Yes but I can't install anything using GitHub links. All topics deal with updating some package using brew but I can't install it anyway ^^